# Explain the equation

Tags: kinematics, speed, distance

Can someone explain me this equation. This is braking distance equation that applies all reaction times ect.. Taken from Bosch Automotive Handbook.
But what does the 25,92 mean there?

v= velocity

tvz = reaction, foot to brake ect.. time, average 1  second

a = max acceleration (decceleration here for braking, 9,81 * friction)

But whats 25,92 here?

[image]

Comment: Unit-independent formula is $s=vt+\frac{v^2}{2a}$. Then if we use unit conversion from km/h to m/s we change $v$ to $v/3.6$, then second term becomes $\frac{(v/3.6)^2}{2a}=\frac{v^2}{25.92a}$

Comment: Interesting.  That kinematic equation for distance is a functional form that I haven't seen before.

Comment: You should never use formulas with magic numbers that should contain units to make it consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying physical equations are
$$\begin{align}
t_\text{AH} &= t_\text{VZ}+\frac{v}{a} \\
s_{AH} &= v\ t_\text{VZ}+\frac{v^2}{2 a}
\end{align} \tag{1}$$
However, these equations require you to use a consistent set of units
for the given quantities
(like time $t$ in s, distance $s$ in m, velocity $v$ in m/s,
acceleration $a$  in m/s$^2$).

But the Bosch Automotive Handbook says

> Equations for $v$ in km/h

To get these equations you can use the conversions
$$\begin{align}
1\text{ m/s} &= 3.6\text{ km/h} \\
(1\text{ m/s})^2 &= (3.6\text{ km/h})^2
 = 12.96\text{ (km/h})^2
\end{align} \tag{2}$$

Putting (1) and (2) together you get

$$\begin{align}
t_\text{AH} &= t_\text{VZ}+\frac{v}{3.6\frac{\text{km/h}}{\text{m/s}}\ a}  \\
s_{AH} &= \frac{v}{3.6\frac{\text{km/h}}{\text{m/s}}}t_\text{VZ}
 +\frac{v^2}{2\cdot 12.96\frac{(\text{km/h})^2}{(\text{m/s})^2}\ a}
\end{align} \tag{3}$$

You see, when inserting a velocity $v$ with unit km/h,
then its km/h cancels with the km/h of the conversion constant.

Your handbook decided to omit the units altogether, which makes the equations simpler,
but also more confusing.

Comment: Thank you, explained very understandably!

Answer (score 0):

It is $2 \times (3.6)^2$. I will take the opportunity to re-obtain the equations you show and explain where that factor came out.

I suppose $t_{\rm AH}$ and $s_{\rm AH}$ are, respectively, the interval of time and distance necessary to halt the car.

This is the graph of the motion considered here
[image]

We have a constant-velocity motion for $t_{\rm VZ}$ seconds - until the driver reacts and brakes, and then a uniformly decelerated motion for $t_{\rm BR}$ seconds. The sum of the two time intervals $t_{\rm VZ}$ and $t_{\rm BR}$ is the total time to halt the car $t_{\rm AH}$. Let us compute this first. After that, the area under the velocity curve will be the total distance needed to halt the car, $s_{\rm AH}$.

To get $t_{\rm BR}$, we use the equation for the velocity in a uniformly decelerated motion

$$v(t) = v_0 - a t$$

where $a$ is positive, the braking deceleration, and $v_0$ is the velocity from which we start braking. As we decelerate to $0\,{\rm m/s}$:

$$0 = v_0 - a t_{\rm BR} \implies t_{\rm BR} = \frac{v_0}{a}$$

summing it to the reaction time, we obtain the total time to halt the car.

$$t_{\rm AH} = t_{\rm VZ} + t_{\rm BR} = t_{\rm VZ} + \frac{v_0}{a}.$$

Note, in all these formulae, time is in seconds and velocity is in ${\rm m}/{\rm s}$. To use a velocity in ${\rm km}/{\rm h}$ every time we have a velocity, we have to divide its value by a factor $3.6$
($\frac{1\,{\rm m}}{1\,{\rm s}} = \frac{10^{-3}\,{\rm km}}{1/3600\,{\rm h}} = 3.6 \frac{\rm km}{\rm h}$).

From the previous equation
$$t_{\rm AH} = t_{\rm VZ} + t_{\rm BR} = t_{\rm VZ} + \frac{v_0[{\rm km/h}]}{3.6 a}.$$

Which is the first equation in your table.

We now compute $s_{\rm AH}$ as the total area under the velocity curve (I am summing the area of a rectangle and a triangle)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
s_{\rm AH} &= v_0 t_{\rm VZ} + \frac{1}{2} v_0 t_{\rm BR} \\ 
           &= v_0 t_{\rm VZ} + \frac{1}{2} v_0 \left( \frac{v_0}{a} \right) \\
           &= v_0 t_{\rm VZ} + \frac{v_0^2}{2 a}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

If we were to convert the latter to use velocities in km/h:

$$s_{\rm AH} = \frac{v_0[{\rm km/h}]}{3.6} t_{\rm VZ} + \frac{v_0[{\rm km/h}]^2}{2 (3.6)^2 a}$$

$2 \times (3.6)^2 = 25.92$ is where that factor is coming from.